# Having trouble compiling scribble document with `#lang scribble/html`

Tags: html, racket, scribble

I'm trying to use Scribble *(Racket v8.0 [cs])* to generate some HTML using [`#lang scribble/html`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble-pp/html.html?q=scribble%2Fhtml) and I've reduced my source file to only the lang statement (to isolate other issues):

```
#lang scribble/html
```

To run the code I'm using terminal:

```
% scribble test.scrbl
```

However, I'm running into the following error during compilation:

```
dynamic-require: name is not provided
  name: 'doc
  module: #<resolved-module-path:"/Users/josh/Desktop/blog architecture/00001 article name/test.scrbl">
  context...:
   .../private/map.rkt:40:19: loop
   .../racket/cmdline.rkt:191:51
   body of "/Applications/Racket v8.0/share/pkgs/scribble-lib/scribble/run.rkt"
```

Obviously something is missing - perhaps a `require` statement? I'm not sure. If you have a better approach to using `#lang scribble/html` I'm open to that as long as I can use the html tags.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello person from 6 months ago! I hope you have solved your problem, but for other travelers here's what worked for me:

Don't use the `scribble` binary, but directly use the `racket` executable.

So, instead of:

```
$ scribble test.scrbl
```

Do

```
$ racket test.scrbl
```

This seemed to work for me with scribble/text, and outputted exactly what I wanted (nothing weirdly processed, nothing "helpfully" escaped - just my text + my racket code executed)